# Vector range issues

Tags: c++, vector, sfml

So I'm trying to create a sort of save/jump system where the player can revert certain aspects of the world to a previous point. For some reason the following code produces vector errors. ("vector subscript out of range")

(entityList is a ptr and recordedEntityList is not)

```
void Map::record()
{
    for(unsigned int x = 0; x < entityList.size(); x++)
    {
        if(entityList[x]->getRewind() == true)
        {
            recordedEntityList.push_back(*entityList[x]);
            printf("%f, %f\n", entityList[x]->getSprite().getPosition().x, entityList[x]->getSprite().getPosition().y);
        }
    }
}

void Map::rewind()
{
    for(unsigned int x = 0; x < entityList.size(); x++)
    {
        if(entityList[x]->getRewind() == true)
        {
            entityList.erase(entityList.begin() + x);
        }
    }

    for(unsigned int y = 0; y < recordedEntityList.size(); y++)
    {
        entityList.push_back(&recordedEntityList[y]);
    }

    recordedEntityList.clear();
}
```

Comment: You can't modify a vector (or any container) you're iterating over without messing things up. You might look into the [Erase-Remove Idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom).

Comment: And BTW, seeing `if (condition == true)` always makes me cry. Just use `if (condition)`.

Comment: You might want to comment if you change your question making my answer obsolete...

Comment: Righto. my apologies. your answer is indeed obsolete, while it was an issue it wasn't the cause.

Comment: I edited it so it is no longer obsolete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `rewind`, you are pushing pointers to elements of `recordedEntityList` into `entityList`, and then you clear `recordedEntityList`. This will cause `entityList` to contain invalidated pointers, and invoke undefined behavior when you access the pointers.

Also, not related to this error, the way you modify the vector while iterating over it in the first loop in `rewind` could cause you to skip entries: If two consecutive entries have `getRewind()` returning `true`, the second one won't be removed.